# Which whl to use when installing PCL module for Python3.9 in Anaconda

Tags: python, pcl

I can't find the Python 3.9 version of whl I need to install the PCL library. I tried to find it on this website ([https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)), but couldn't find it. Is there any relevant guide?

Answer (score 2):

None. You should not mix wheels with anaconda packages if you can avoid it. Install it from conda-forge instead:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pcl
```